# SpriteKit SKAction run multiple actions before calling a completitionBlock

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I can call

```
- (void)runAction:(SKAction *)action completion:(void (^)(void))block
```

but how to call one completion block after running an action on 4 different `SKNode` s?

basically what I need is to perform some action once this method has been called on all 4 SKNode

```
- (void)rotateToSquareIndex:(SquareIndex)squareIndex
{
    self.squareIndex = squareIndex;
    int index        = self.index;
    SKAction * action;
    switch (squareIndex)
    {
        case indexTopLeft:
            action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(16.f, 16.f) duration:.3];
            index -= 1;
            break;
        case indexTopRight:
            action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(48.f, 16.f) duration:.3];
            index += 10;
            break;
        case indexBottomRight:
            action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(48.f, 48.f) duration:.3];
            index += 1;
            break;
        case indexBottomLeft:
            action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(16.f, 48.f) duration:.3];
            index -= 10;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    self.index = index;

    [self runAction:action];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? How exactly are you going about calling this method on the different nodes?

Comment: you can sequence the moveTo actions and in each completionBlock you increase a counter variable (on a central class like the scene) and the block where the counter was increased to "4" runs the final completion method or block

Comment: Are they all being called at the same time or is the calling of this method dynamic?

Comment: they are called one after the other but I'm thinking about implementing a counter variable on the SKScene I'm just worried about multithreading as I dont know on which thread the action is run.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't think there's any built in or "sexy" way of achieving what you're after, but here's at least a solution I believe should work:

You need a mutable array, a private property if you write code the way I do, `squareIndexesRotated`

```
- (void)rotateToSquareIndex:(SquareIndex)squareIndex
{
    self.squareIndex = squareIndex;
    int index        = self.index;
    NSNumber *indexNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
    if (![self.squareIndexesRotated containsObject:indexNumber]){
        [self.squareIndexesRotated addObject:indexNumber];
    }

    // your action + switch stuff

    if ([self.squareIndexesRotated count] == 4){
        // Do whatever you want here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying to do something like this.

```
    YourAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(100, 280)duration:5.0];

    SKAction *completion = [SKAction runBlock:^{

    }];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[ YourActions ,etc... ]];
    [YourNode runAction:sequence];
```